# Symfony 3 Infinite Scroll for Announce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, symfony-3.3

I have an website with a lot of announce.

I want to make an infinite scroll loading for my announce.

Actually, this is what i have in my twig.html

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}

</br>
        <div class="container">


        <!-- Menu -->

        {% include '::announce/menu.html.twig' %}


        {% for announce in announces|slice(0, 4) %}

        <!-- Detail Announce -->

            {% include '::announce/' ~ game ~ '/preview.html.twig' %}

        {% endfor %}

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I try to add something like that

```
{% block javascripts %}

 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            var count = 2;
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                       loadArticle(count);
                       count++;
                    }
            });

            function loadArticle(pageNumber){   
                    $('a#inifiniteLoader').show('fast');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "{{ asset('ajax/ajax.html.twig') }}",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no="+ pageNumber + '&loop_file=loop',
                        success: function(html){
                            $('a#inifiniteLoader').hide('1000');
                            $("#content").append(html);    // This will be the div where our content will be loaded
                        }
                    });
                return false;
            }

        });
```

But every loop, i got html text but twig doesn't works with my ajax/ajax.html.twig.

Do you have a more simple function for making a loop when scrolling with

```
{% for announce in announces|slice(NBR, NBR+4) %}
```

Or just a correction in my previous code?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 problems here:

- you have to render your twig file,
- your mechanism will be very slow when you have lots of announcements.

We successfully developed a continuous scroll feature in a different way.
We didn't load all articles at once, but just enough to populate the page.
Ajax call was created towards the controller's method with a next page as one of the arguments.

The controller's method called repository to get correct amount of next articles and returned them in a rendered twig file.